# Broken pipe error when proxying long file upload request

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, reverse

Recently and overnight, Apache's error logs from a couple of nodejs servers have been filling with this:

> [proxy:error] [pid xxx] (32)Broken pipe: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59835] AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:9001 (127.0.0.1), referer: https://tubedu.org/videos/upload

And

> [proxy_http:error] [pid xxx] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59835] AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:9001 (127.0.0.1) from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (), referer: https://tubedu.org/videos/upload

It happens when users try to upload large files. When the transfer is done, users get a 502 bad gateway error. This happens randomly but the larger is the file, most likely it is to happen.

Thanks!

EDIT: It seems that the error happens 60 seconds before de connection is established. About the first error message, sometimes it shows that one and sometimes shows this one:

> [proxy:error] [pid xxx] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58520] AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:9000 (127.0.0.1), referer: https://video.hardlimit.com/videos/upload

I've tried increasing timeouts in apache2.conf like this:

```
Timeout 900
ProxyTimeout 900
KeepAliveTimeout 600
```

with no result.

Finally, I've added to my virtualhost, this:

```
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
```

and this:

```
ProxyPass /           http://127.0.0.1:9000/ timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/ timeout=600
```

But the error always happens 60 seconds before the transfer begins.

EDIT 2: I've modified the value of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout to 120 (it was 60). But it didn't work.

EDIT 3: Apparently it is a new "feature" of NodeJS 12.19.0 witch kills the connection 60 seconds before it is established. I solved it by using Nginx. This web server make a new connection just when the file has been uploaded to its buffer. Then, the server transfers it thru NodeJS witch takes way less than 60 seconds.

Comment: God bless you for adding edits relating to your troubleshooting and also the fix that worked for you. Thanks.